# Find Column Header and determine the number of active rows below

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to start off that I am new to using VBA in Excel. I am simply trying to locate a cell in my workbook (A column header) and use that information to determine a range based on the row below down to the last active row.

I have the below, though I run into object property errors.

```
'Identify the starting range Cell
Dim Acct_Start As String 
'Determine the range length
Dim Acct_Lines As Long

'Locate All of the Security Numbers
Acct_Start = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Account Number").Offshet(1, 0).Address
Acct_Lines = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlDown).Row
```

My End goal is to use this information to cut the first and last digit off of my values. I.E. my data comes as x123456x and I want it to be 123456.

If my above code worked, I would the put it through the below TextToColumn trimmer.

```
    'Clean Up Security Numbers
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(Acct_Start), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfor:=Array(Array(0, Acct_Lines), Array(1, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(Acct_Start), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, Acct_Lines), Array(6, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Please let me know if I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: is it a table or a normal range?

Comment: You have typo in `Offshet(1,0)` and you should use `xlUp` instead of `xlDown`.

Comment: Do you have to use a macro?  What about using a combination of the MID and LEN functions to select the middle portion of each cell?  This would keep your source data intact as well.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav This is a normal range.

Comment: @Egan Wolf Why do you say xlUp should be used. Everything I have read indicates I should be using xlDown

Comment: @Shimeon Though that would complete this initial task, this is part of a larger macro procedure I am developing.

Comment: @BenL Sorry, I didn't check SO for a while.
`Rows.Count` gives you an amount of rows in whole sheet. `Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column)` will return the last cell in active column. `End(xlDown)` behaviour is the same as pressing `Ctrl+arrow_down`. So, your code will always return the last row in sheet. What you want to do is: from the last cell in column GO UP until you find some values, then return row number.

Answer (score 0):

If by "last active row" you mean last cell with data, this should give you the desired range:

```
Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range, rngFull As Range

Set rngStart = Range("1:1").Find("c1").Offset(1, 0)
Set rngEnd = rngStart.End(xlDown)
Set rngFull = Range(rngStart, rngEnd)
```

You have to replace "c1".

Comment: I actioned the above code exactly as indicated above though I received another error message

Run-time error 91:
Object variable or With block variable not set

Is this due to the variable being classified as Range? Should it be String?

Comment: No, it is a range. In the OP you wanted to "to determine a range". If you need the address of that range, it's `rngFull.Address`.

Comment: Unless you're searching for "c1", you shouldn't run it exactly as indicated but replace "c1" with your header.

Comment: I am encountering this error in the second line (where I set rngEnd). Since I am trying to find a value inside of a cell, is LookIn required in my find statement?

Comment: I don't think you need to specify LookIn but you may try with xlValues. If the search string is not found, rngStart will be nothing and you can't get the .End of nothing. So either make sure you always search for existing strings or add some code for the case when the string is not found.